# Middleware en next.js parece no hacer nada

Tags: javascript, nodejs, reactjs, nextjs, middleware

Estoy utilizando la versión 13.1.1 de Next e intenté crear un  Middleware básico siguiéndolo la [documentación](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) algo parecido a esto:

```
// middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

// This function can be marked `async` if using `await` inside
export function middleware(request) {
  console.log('xd')
  return NextResponse.redirect(new URL('/', request.url))
}

// See "Matching Paths" below to learn more
export const config = {
  matcher: '/dashboard',
}
```

Sin embargo cuando navego a `/dashboard` no veo el texto del console.log ni me redirecciona al `/`.

El middleware está dentro del directorio page y lo reconoce porque si escribo un matcher vacío es decir `''` se queja.

Anexo que actualmente cuándo trató de realizar el build me da el siguiente error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resuelto, el problema se debe a que el `middleware.js` no debe estar dentro de la carpeta `pages`, sino al mismo nivel de la misma. Es decir:

```
...
|- pages/
|- middleware.js
...
```